# How to sync web app authentication with chrome extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, next.js, google-chrome-extension, next.js13

I have been working on a project that involves users signing up on my main web app. The web app is created using Nextjs 14 with the new app router support and I used the next-auth ( Which saves user sessions in the cookies ) to make the user sign in. Now I want to sync the authentication state between my web app and the Chrome extension, so for example, the user can authenticate on the main web app and when the user clicks on the Chrome extension on a separate tab, I want to make sure that the chrome extension shows based on the authenticated routes. It should also be able to make requests to the protected api routes if signed up.
I inspected the network tab of the popular chrome extensions from the background dev tools and it seems that they call their api endpoints to check the state of authentication, i.e. they do not save the tokens in the cookie or local storage to check the authentication state.
How can I enable something like this, I tried finding tutorials online, but no help yet

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the login through the extension, you will need to put a few things together:

- a `background worker` that will watch for changes in the cookies of your browser
- a `listener` on the extension side, that will listen to events broadcasted by your background worker. There will be one instance per chrome extension, meaning one instance per opened tab.

The `background worker` will have one instance per instance of browser running, meaning there will be only one source of events. It will start when your browser starts, and shutdown when your browser shuts down (except crash or manually stopped).

`background.js`

`REACT_APP_NEXTAUTH_SECRET` is the same one used in your frontend. Sadly it is sort of a security hazard, but I never found a better way to decode the cookie to get the JWT. If you find a way to use the cookie as is, it's better.
`REACT_APP_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `REACT_APP_COOKIE_NAME` are unique to your app, and the best way to find out is by `console.log` the cookie changing and see their value. You should put the values of the changing cookie when you log into your website.

```
// Notify each extension instance of the cookie change
function broadcastMessageToAllTabs(message: object) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ status: "complete" }, (tabs) => {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      if (tab.id) {
        chrome.tabs
          .sendMessage(tab.id, message)
          .catch((e) =>
            console.error(
              `Could not send message to the tab [${tab.id}/${tab.title}]`,
              e,
            ),
          );
      }
    });
  });
}

// Decodes the token contained within the cookie
async function setToken(token: string | null) {
  const decoded = token
    ? ((await decode({
        token,
        secret: process.env.REACT_APP_NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
      })) as { user: { accessToken: string } })
    : undefined;
  broadcastMessageToAllTabs({ token: decoded?.user?.accessToken || null });
}

// Adds a listener for cookies changing in the browser, e.g. after login or logout
chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(async (reason) => {
  if (
    reason.cookie.domain === process.env.REACT_APP_COOKIE_DOMAIN &&
    reason.cookie.name === process.env.REACT_APP_COOKIE_NAME
  ) {
    // On overwrite, removed is also true when it is actually updating the cookie, so we avoid to remove it for flickering
    await setToken(
      reason.removed && reason.cause !== "overwrite"
        ? null
        : reason.cookie.value,
    );
  }
});
```

`my-plugin.ts`

Anywhere within your extension code, you should add a listener for the changes broadcasted by the background worker.

```
  const handleMessage = (message: any) => {
    if ("token" in message) {
      // Got the token from the worker, save it somewhere so you can use it
    }
  };

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
  // Ideally somewhere if you are releasing resources it is good to unsubscribe within your extension to avoid memory leaks and issues
  // chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handleMessage);
```

This part should get you started when you log in and out of your website. Now there is one extra case not covered by it, which is if you already logged-in and open a new tab. Your extension will not receive any log-in event since you already did, which would require you to login again each time you open a tab.

To address this issue, we should implement communication from the extension to the background worker. In the `background.ts`, let's add

```
// Listens to messages broadcasted, and eventually answers with the current cookie if any
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  (async function () {
    if (request.type === "GET_COOKIE") {
      const cookie = await chrome.cookies.getAll({
        domain: process.env.REACT_APP_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        name: process.env.REACT_APP_COOKIE_NAME,
      });
      if (cookie.length) {
        const decoded = cookie[0].value
          ? ((await decode({
              token: cookie[0].value,
              secret: process.env.REACT_APP_NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
            })) as { user: { accessToken: string } })
          : undefined;
        sendResponse({ token: decoded?.user?.accessToken || null });
        return;
      }
    }
    sendResponse({ token: null });
  })();
  return true;
});
```

and within `my-plugin.ts`, should be called any time the extension instance starts

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "GET_COOKIE" }, (response) => {
          if (response) {
            // Got a response from the worker, eventually sending us the token
          } else {
            console.error("Got an empty response for GET_COOKIE");
          }
        });
```

Pro tip: to help you debug and understand what is going on, you can also open the console of the background worker by going to your settings / extensions inside of Chrome and open your own extension (here is an arbitrary example with React Dev Tools):
[image: inspect views]